# Javascript Geolocation: Storing coordinates in an array

Tags: javascript, geolocation, coordinates, latitude-longitude, navigator

I created an HTML button:

```
...onclick="stLoc();"/>
```

which gears the stLoc() Javascript function.

My intention is to store the latitude inside the `vaulesX`array.

Here's my code:

```
var valuesX=[];

//This is to show the current position:

function handleLoc(pos)  {
var a=pos.coords.latitude;
var b=pos.coords.longitude;
var p = new L.LatLng(+a, +b);
mark(p);
}

//Here I intend to store the latitude using "valuesX.push":

function stLoc(pos)  {
var a=pos.coords.latitude;
var b=pos.coords.longitude;
var p = new L.LatLng(+a, +b);
mark(p);
valuesX.push(a);
}

//And this is to enable the geolocation:
function handleErr(pos) {
document.write("could not determine location");
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleLoc,handleErr);
}
else {
document.write("geolocation not supported");
}
```

The output I get is an empty array.

Comment: How do you actually pass `pos` to `stLoc(pos)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your **stLoc()** function is expecting **pos** object to be passed as first parameter.

But in your HTML part of example you're not passing this parameter to function:

`<a "onclick="stLoc();">`

This causes the error and the application flow breaks.

**Update:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="return stLoc();">button</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var valuesX=[],
    lastPos={a: -1, b: -1};
//This is to show the current position:

function handleLoc(pos)  {
    // in event handler remember lastPos to use it in stLoc on click.
    lastPos.a = pos.coords.latitude;
    lastPos.b = pos.coords.longitude;
    var p = new L.LatLng(lastPos.a, lastPos.b);
    mark(p);
}

//Here I intend to store the latitude using "valuesX.push":

function stLoc()  {
    if(lastPos.a != -1) {
        valuesX.push(lastPos.a);
    }
    return false;
}

//And this is to enable the geolocation:
function handleErr(pos) {
    document.write("could not determine location");
}

if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleLoc,handleErr);
}
else {
    document.write("geolocation not supported");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add console.log(pos); before var a=pos.coords.latitude; and read the output in the console? Then put console.log(a); before valuesX.push(a); and read the output. Seems some code before push() method invocation throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

For guys looking out for code to implement this functionality in a different way..
Here is the code

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function geoSuccess(e){
   var lat = e.coords.latitude;
   var lon = e.coords.longitude;
   var myLoc = "Latitude: " + lat + '<br />Longitude: ' + lon;
   $("#mylocation").html(myLoc);
}
function geoFailed(e){
   $("#mylocation").html("Failed");
}
window.onload=function(e){
    if ( navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoFailed);
    } else {
       // Error (Could not get location)
       $("#mylocation").html("Failed");
    }
}
</script>
<div id="mylocation"></div>
```